# Proper way to dispose screens in Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, dispose

What is the proper way of completely disposing of a screen in Libgdx? Currently If I click where a button was on my previous screen the button still does what it would of done if I were on that screen. Should I be `.dispose()`-ing everything I can in the `dispose()` method? or is there a simpler way to dispose of everything on screen?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easier way. These classes do not share any kind of common "`Disposable`" interface, or anything like that, to do it automatically. Everything that has a `dispose()` method needs to be disposed manually when it's not needed anymore.

This is also valid for the `Screens` themselves. When switching `Screens` they do not get disposed automatically, but you need to do that yourself (before calling `Game.setScreen()`).

On the other hand, this is not a big deal. Just look through everything in your `Screen` and check whether it has to be disposed or not. If there is a dispose method, call it in `dispose()` of the `Screen`.

BUT this does not explain your behaviour about invisible buttons from the last `Screen`. I suppose you use a `Stage` and used `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);`. This setting will not be changed when you change the screen and you have to set the input processor to the `Stage` of your current `Screen`, or to whatever that handles the input in your current `Screen`. That way the "old" stage will not catch any inputs anymore.

Comment: As for all the variables? How would I handle them?

Comment: @user2341336 Which variables exactly do you mean? I keep most of the things that need to be disposed on a Screen switch as a private property of the Screen class itself, because it logically belongs to the Screen.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that this issue is not passing the inpur processor a new stage. this will result in "ghost" buttons as described.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately [LibGDX API documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Screen.html) says

> Note that dispose() is not called automatically.

So what I do is disposing all disposables (such as `Stage`, `Skin`, `Texture` ... etc) inside the `hide()` method in the Screen because `hide()` is called automatically and it works very well!

example:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
...
    @Override
    public void hide() {
        mainStage.dispose();
        playGroundStage.dispose();
        controller.dispose();
        labelActor.dispose();
    }
...
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend disposing things inside the hide()-method as this gets called on android if someone calls you